# What does it mean in Substrate when a value is stored at Twox128(Prefix::pallet_prefix()) ++ Twox128(Prefix::STORAGE_PREFIX)?

Tags: substrate

From docs:

> pub struct StorageValue<Prefix, Value, QueryKind = OptionQuery, OnEmpty = GetDefault>(_);

```
A type that allow to store a value.

Each value is stored at:

Twox128(Prefix::pallet_prefix()) ++ Twox128(Prefix::STORAGE_PREFIX)
```

What does the "Twox128(Prefix::pallet_prefix()) ++ Twox128(Prefix::STORAGE_PREFIX)" mean here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is telling you how the storage key is calculated by combining two hashes. From the [docs](https://docs.substrate.io/v3/advanced/storage/):

> To calculate the key for a simple Storage Value, take the [TwoX](https://github.com/Cyan4973/xxHash) 128
> hash of the name of the pallet that contains the Storage Value and
> append to it the TwoX 128 hash of the name of the Storage Value
> itself.

e.g.

```
twox_128("Sudo")                   = "0x5c0d1176a568c1f92944340dbfed9e9c"
twox_128("Key")                    = "0x530ebca703c85910e7164cb7d1c9e47b"
twox_128("Sudo") + twox_128("Key") = "0x5c0d1176a568c1f92944340dbfed9e9c530ebca703c85910e7164cb7d1c9e47b"
```

Comment: please take a look at the Substrate StackExchange proposal and support it: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126136

Comment: I'm already committed! Only a few more to go...